# SHA1 verification of external deb package before install

Tags: debian, dpkg, hashsum

I have a .deb file and its SHA1 checksum information.

How do I check the .deb file's authenticity using this checksum before installing?

There's many entries on Google for "how to verify checksums for installed packages" which is mind-boggingly useless yet none for checking BEFORE installing. Bonus points if you can explain why people are checking files AFTER installing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check whether your package matches the SHA1 sum you have, run

```
sha1sum /path/to/package.deb
```

and compare the output.

If you have the sum in a file of the form

```
sum  package.deb
```

you can run `sha1sum -c shafile` to check the sum directly.

To determine the authenticity of the package, you’ll need to determine the authenticity of the SHA1 sum.

People check MD5 sums after installation for a variety of reasons; the one that makes sense in my opinion is to check for involuntary corruption (*e.g.* after disk errors, or an operator error). The MD5 sums available after installation are shipped in the package and are stored locally, so they don’t provide any external authentication.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. This was an exercise in extreme frustration. Something as simple and as useful as checksum verification of external packages should be done automatically instead of this random bs

Comment: That’s what package repositories are for ;-). (Well, one of the features they can provide.)

Comment: And use `sha256sum <filename>.deb` for SHA-256 checksums.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sha1sum file.deb` to check a `deb` package

> people are checking files AFTER installing them.

If a SUM of a file is modified people may reinstall/remove this package. The [`debsums`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/debsums.1.html) utility can be used to accomplish this task.